# SSL error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail

I was unable to send an email in laravel 5,when I click send it return this message

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 95:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Here is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=**********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

file mail.php

```
return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp-relay.gmail.comt'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];
```

I researched for hours but couldn't resolve this, any advice ?
P/S: I use Windows 10 and XAMPP for Webserver

Comment: Have you tried using `tls` encryption instead of `ssl`?

Answer (score 4):

Change in `.env` file:

**MAIL_DRIVER=smtp to MAIL_DRIVER=mail**

Comment: Warning: mail will send email through your local machine. don't do this if you're planning to use a remote SMTP server.
it's also deprecated. see https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/866

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible solutions:
1) Get rid of "tls" and leave MAIL_ENCRYPTION as blank.
2) If you are on MacOS Sierra and want to keep your 'tls' setting, type these two lines in your terminal/shall:
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/certs
$ sudo curl -o /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/cert.pem https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

The two lines basically help you create the default folder and import the latest certificate store from curl.haxx.se.
Here is the source article I got if interested: https://andrewyager.com/2016/10/04/php-on-macos-sierra-cant-access-ssl-data/comment-page-1/#comment-52

Hope it helps.﻿

Comment: @AlonfromDataPlusResearch good my answer was useful to you, a up vote will be appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file

the host should be smtp.gmail.com
From and name should not be null
change your mail encryption from ssl to tsl

dont forget to turn on less secure app in your google accout setting

Answer (score -1):

Go to  location **\vendor\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php**
at line 259 and comment the following:

`//$options = array();`

and add.

`$options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);`

Comment: Files in "vendor" directory are not meant to be edited. If you think there is an error, fork that repository and make pull request into main.